# Picklist in SOSL on an encrypted org

Tags: picklist, sosl

Can anyone tell me if a picklist field is encrypted and I use SOSL, is there a limitation that it still wont match it in a query?

Im on an ecrypted org and I am doing a query:

```
FIND {golf*} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Call_Report__c(Name, Meeting_Type__c, Client__r.Name, Id order by Id limit 1000 )
```

There is a record that has Golf as its meeting type, but meeting_type__c is a picklist. If i use a different search term, such as Dublin where the meeting is located, then it finds it. Location is a text field though.

So is there a limitation on encrypted objects picklists in SOSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOSL can't search picklist fields at all. You can only generally search in text, auto-number, external ID-enabled, text area, long text area, phone, and email fields.

Comment: @discodowney Since I see you're using one in your query, I'll add that encrypted fields can't be used in an ORDER BY clause. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_considerations_general.htm.